# How can I use the Google Docs API to get the HTML from a Google Doc?

Tags: html, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am using the Google Docs API from `googleapis@39` and I want to get the HTML. What I currently have is a way to get [this object](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents) from the API without a problem. I can't find a way to turn that object into HTML. Can someone please assist me? I have already tried a few different approaches to this problem such as trying to get the HTML from the Google API directly and converting the object into HTML.

Thank you!

Comment: I cannot understand about `turn that object into HTML` of `What I currently have is a way to get this object from the API without a problem. I can't find a way to turn that object into HTML.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? In your case, do you want to convert Google Document to HTML? By the way, from `googleapis@39`, is your script for Node.js?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand that you wanted to convert Google Document to HTML data. In this case, your goal can be achieved with the method of "Files: export" of Drive API. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export) I think that this is the answer for your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could understand that you wanted to convert Google Document to HTML data.

In this case, your goal can be achieved with the method of "Files: export" of Drive API. Ref I think that this is the answer for your question.